# Intellij doesn't recompile code changes when I do a rerun?

Tags: intellij-idea

I made code changes in a scala intellij project and when I rerun then (by using the green play button), it seems like the changes don't get recompiled and the IDE runs the previous version of the code. Why is this happening? Like, I literally added "println" there that has to get printed, but it doesn't, until I manually do "mvn clean install" on the project.

Comment: Show your run configuration. Is build included into it?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov what are the steps that I need to take to obtain that configuration?